# How do I access Java classes from a Tampermonkey script?

Tags: javascript, java, tampermonkey

I have a Java class, for a MWE let's say

```
package myjava;

public class Foo {
   public Foo() {}
   public int bar() {
      return 1;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(new Foo().bar());
   }
}
```

Its location is added to the CLASSPATH variable, so for example writing

```
java myjava.Foo
```

in the Windows command line works.

Now I would like to call this method from a Tampermonkey script in Google Chrome. The examples I have seen at various places don't seem to work:

```
var Foo = Java.type("myjava.Foo");
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = foo.bar();
```

(as suggested by the [documentation at Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/javascript.html)) and

```
var foo = new Packages.myjava.Foo();
var bar = foo.bar();
```

(and some other variations) all throw an error at the first line, not because of the particular class not being known, but the first identifier (`Java`, `Packages`, I even tried simply using `new myjava.Foo()`).

Clearly, I don't seem to know how to reference a Java class from the script, but I also cannot find an example that works. What would be the correct way to do it?

EDIT: As it has been brought to my attention, the website I linked to provides code that is not even supposed to be valid for the web browser's JavaScript engine.

Comment: First of all java code is not been compile. Because you can't call bar() method in main method without crating a Foo object.

Comment: 1) Tampermonkey runs userscripts, which use JavaScript, not Java. 2) Scripts can't access locally installed apps such as java

Comment: You don't. That document is about embedding scripts inside a Java application.

Comment: @MustafaÇil Yeah, sorry about that, I just quickly added a main method to the MWE on the site. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I managed to find a workaround, though it's a bit of a hassle:

One can use `GM_xmlhttpRequest` to send the arguments inside a `POST` request to a PHP file on localhost, where a local web server passes them on as command line parameters to the Java class in question. It then returns the result via `echo`, and the resulting string can be read from the `responseText` field and interpreted in the browser script.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work from tampermonkey since those scripts are ran on the browser's javascript engine (afaik). The `Java.type` function is a [Nashorn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/nashorn/nashorn-java-api.htm#JSNUG112) extension, which means it is only available when the script is ran on Nashorn. As the documentation mentions (which seems to be the place you found that snippet):

> This section describes how to access Java from a script **interpreted by the Nashorn engine.**

Nashorn is the Oracle JDK implementation of a javascript engine. It is written in Java, so as an extension it offers the ability to interop with Java. But Java and javascript are separate languages, so there is no reason other javascript engines would *have* to provide the same Java interop capabilities (not every JS runtime is strapped to a JVM, like Nashorn is).

Comment: Ah I see, my bad for not noticing that. And would there be a way to refer to Java classes when using the browser's engine?

Comment: @Taederias Technically that would depend on the engine used. But afaik it's not possible in any of the browsers that support web extensions (tampermonkey).

Comment: @JohnVernee So then is there no way to use externally compiled code as a subroutine in a script? Would I need to reimplement everything in JavaScript for it to work?

Comment: @JornVerneeOkay then, thank you for clearing that up.